# Chaining async actions in redux-observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-observable, typesafe-actions

I'm using reduxjs with the redux-observable middleware.

I need to firstly fetch the user data from an api. After the fetch is complete this data is written to my redux store, after that I want to fetch additional data, which depends on the result of the user fetch.

So for example, I need to first fetch the user, after that I know the classId of the user, then I can fetch this class, after that I know the teacherId, so I can fetch the teacher.

```js
export const fetchAllEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootAction, RootState, RootServices> = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    isActionOfType(fetchAllAsync.request),
    switchMap(() => {
        return of(
          fetchUserData.request(),
          fetchClass.request(state$.value.business.user.classId),
          fetchTeacher.request(state$.value.business.class.teacherId),
        );
    }),
  );
};
```

How do I 'await' an async redux action? Or is there another way?

I thought about making an epic just for that scenario, but that would result in a lot of duplicated code, as then I would have to different epics for `fetchUserData`, one which only fetches the user data and emit a success. And the other one, which emits success and fetchClass.request, with the id as payload.

I now found [this](https://medium.com/@jmalojlo/sequencing-asynchronous-actions-with-redux-observable-1d050f30d2fb) article, but the problem is, as I'm using typesafe actions, I cannot simply use the meta property, as it does not exist on that type

Comment: [typesafe-actions - with-redux-observable-epics](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#with-redux-observable-epics)

Comment: I know that doc, I'm already using that, but now I want to chain the calls so I read about the meta param, but currently I'm failing to use it. I'm creating the actions like this: createAsyncAction(
  'business/FETCH_USER_DATA_REQUEST',
  'business/FETCH_USER_DATA_SUCCESS',
  'business/FETCH_USER_DATA_FAILURE',
)<void, User, string>();